# Bootstrap-select - how to fire event on change multiple

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have this situation:

i cannot get the selected value of a bootstrap-select with multiple=true
i can only get the first item?
so, when i first select Mustard, i get the alert for "Mustard", but when i select after that Ketchup, i still get "Mustard"?

How can i get the value of the last selected or deselected item?

```js
$(function() {

  $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    alert(selected);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue in your code is `$(this).find("option:selected").val()`

As @Guruprasad Rao said there is no need of looping just remove `.find("option:selected")` in above line

```js
$(function() {

  $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    alert(selected);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

And if you want to get the last element selected then you have use array and store the element that is selected in it

Comment: **Another solution** This doesn't get's the value of last `un-selected` option, so instead try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944647/bootstrap-select-on-click-get-clicked-value)

Answer (score 2):

You might need to loop through `options selected` when there are multiple. For ex as below:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = []; //array to store value
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(key,value){
        selected.push(value.innerHTML); //push the text to array
    });
    alert(selected);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```