# Bootstrap-select on click get clicked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using a jQuery plug-in: **bootstrap-select.js** my HTML is select(multiple) -> option. I would like to get the currently clicked on option value when a user selects or deselects the option.

**Example**: User selects Item 4 = console.log item 4. Then the user also selects Item 2 = console.log item 2. Currently i'm getting item 4, item 2... they are always in a array and not individual.

My end goal is to show and hide divs on the page depending on what the user has selected. There will be multiple select option fields.

**HTML code:**

```
<fieldset class="dreamT">
   <select name="team" id="team" multiple class="dropdown selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick form-control" title="Pelaajat" data-width="100%" data-size="auto" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 2">
    <optgroup>
        <option value="item 1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="item 2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="item 3">Item 3</option>
        <option value="item 4">Item 4</option>
        <option value="item 5">Item 5</option>
        <option disabled value="item 6">Item 6</option>
    </optgroup>
   </select>
</fieldset>
```

**JS code:**

```
$("select#team").on("change", function(value){
   var This      = $(this);
   var selectedD = $(this).val();
   console.log(selectedD);
});
```

Current output: `["item 1", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5"]`

Plug-in site: [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: have you tried `$("select#team").on("click", function(event, value)`?

Comment: @Osuwariboy no? what do you mean? How would i implement that? :D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As described in the [bootstrap-select events](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#events) you can use **changed.bs.select** event.

This event fires after the select's value has been changed. It passes through the following 4 arguments:

- event
- clickedIndex
- isSelected
- previousValue

```js
$(function () {
  $('#team').selectpicker();
  $("#team").on("changed.bs.select", function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, oldValue) {
      if (clickedIndex == null && isSelected == null) {
          var selectedItems = ($(this).selectpicker('val') || []).length;
          var allItems = $(this).find('option:not([disabled])').length;
          if (selectedItems == allItems) {
              console.log('seleted all');
          } else {
              console.log('deseleted all');
          }
      } else {
          var selectedD = $(this).find('option').eq(clickedIndex).text();
          console.log('selectedD: ' + selectedD +  ' oldValue: ' + oldValue);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<fieldset class="dreamT">
    <select name="team" id="team" multiple class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick form-control" title="" multiple data-actions-box="true"
            data-width="100%" data-size="auto" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 2">
        <optgroup>
            <option value="item 1">Item 1</option>
            <option value="item 2">Item 2</option>
            <option value="item 3">Item 3</option>
            <option value="item 4">Item 4</option>
            <option value="item 5">Item 5</option>
            <option disabled value="item 6">Item 6</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with Select All / Deselect All options (data-actions-box="true") then clickedIndex and newValue and null :(

Comment: @PavelNovák I'm sorry, but it was an old answer and the plugin was updated. Snippet updated.

Answer (score 2):

Or just have the event on the option elements...

```
$("option").on("click", function(value){
        var This = $(this);
        var selectedD = $(this).val();
        console.log(selectedD);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adjavaherian/ssqz4sh8/

Comment: This does not work with the plug-in. Somehow it returns nothing. I don't know why but if i use click it does nothing.

Comment: that's because click doesn't happen on option, it happens on span that represents it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log(("#your-id option:selected").text());
```

ref : [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-get-selected-text-from-a-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Or just look for any changes on the element and get the value if changed.

```
$("#components").on("change", function(e) {
  var selected = document.querySelector("#components").selectedOptions[0].value
  alert(selected)
});
```